# Which is the most viewed Cumbia of all time?

Tags: cumbia

This chart claims that "Mi ex tenía razón" by Shakira and Karol G is the most viewed Cumbia of all time. [Most Viewed Cumbia YouTube Music Videos Of All Time](https://chartex.com/all-songs-on-youtube/filters/tag-1-genre-cumbia-8/period/1-month/sort/youtube-views-desc) with 22.6 million views.

But I know many other cumbias which hundreds of millions of views larger than that.

This one,

[Rei, Callejero Fino - Tu Turrito](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AtalMwsn7fs) even though is a fusion of Cumbia, Reggaeton and Trap, it has a rhythmic part of Cumbia (also one of Reggaeton and Trap) and I can tell the melodic part is done with Kontakt synthetizer which is a synthetizer used for Cumbia Villera. Also these other 2 are pure Cumbia Villera,

[Damas gratis me vas a extrañar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iTNdq-GOVXc) has 468 million views and [No te creas tan importante](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j6CUfl4aX9s) has 535 million views. And I bet there are many other with hundred million views.

I can't really tell why that chart is so horrible wrong but I guess it's Cumbia isnt so widely known outside Latin America but extremely popular in it. So my question is,

Which is the most viewed Cumbia of all time? Hasnt anyone seriously attempted to determine this?